# Assemblies don't copy to bin directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have solution with 13 project. One project is `WinForm (EArchive)`, other is `class library`. When I click on F5(Debug) or F6(Build Solution) the assemblies is building OK, but they don't copy to bin directory of `EArchive`. When I click right mouse button on `EArchive` and select `Build` then works(but not all, for example don't copy resource file).

I have tried:
1. Delete all bin and obj folders.
2. Rebuild All.
3. Clean command from context menu.

Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the project reference to the class library marked as *Copy local*?

Comment: In that case we would need more information about your solution and project files. Likely something is messed up with the project settings... *but there are a lot of project settings!*

Answer (score 0):

(I realize this is an old post, but it's still unanswered.)

This sounds like the WinForm project is not set to be built in the solution's build configuration.  I've encountered problems like this where a project will unexpectedly be unchecked in the `Configuration Manager` (under the `Build` menu).  Check there.